# Error php artisan migrate stripe cashier

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, stripe

Tengo ya un proyecto bastante avanzado hecho con laravel en la que tengo mi base de datos con las tablas, vistas y sus funcionalidades, mi idea ahora es utilizar stripe para poder realizar compras, leyendo la documentación he usado el comando composer require laravel/cashier y tras esto php artisan migrate para que stripe me cree sus campos dentro de la tabla users, el problema viene aquí, stripe espera que tenga una tabla llamada users pero mi tabla se llama usuarios, ¿no hay forma de decirle a stripe que mi tabla usuarios es la users que está esperando? La otra solución que se me ocurre es crear una nueva migración llamada users, pero no le veo mucho sentido tener una tabla llamada users y otra usuarios en la misma bd. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

La documentación es siempre tu mejor aliado. Te hace falta [publicer y editar](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/billing#database-migrations) las migraciones de `Stripe`:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cashier-migrations"
```

En `create_customer_columns` tienes que editar la tabla que extiende:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        // En esta línea cambia 'users' por el nombre de tu tabla
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('stripe_id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->string('pm_type')->nullable();
            $table->string('pm_last_four', 4)->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        // En esta línea cambia 'users' por el nombre de tu tabla
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn([
                'stripe_id',
                'pm_type',
                'pm_last_four',
                'trial_ends_at',
            ]);
        });
    }
};
```

Es posible que también tengas que [editar el modelo](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/billing#billable-model) con el que trabaja `Stripe` ya que por defecto es `User`.